# Añadir una fila a una tabla HTML

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

Tengo un código el cual quiero que añada filas segun se vayan necesitando y tengo ahora mismo este código.

```js
$("#insert-more").click(function() {
  $("#mytable").each(function() {
    var tds = '<tr>';
    jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function() {
      tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
    });
    tds += '</tr>';
    if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
      $('tbody', this).append(tds);
    } else {
      $(this).append(tds);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12'>
    <button class="btn btn-success addmore" type="button" id="insert-more"> Add New Row</button>
    <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="5%">Cantidad</th>
          <th width="18%">Descripción del articulo</th>
          <th width="5%">Price Unitario</th>
          <th width="5%">%DTO</th>
          <th width="7%">Precio Total</th>
          <th width="12%">Inspección de recepción</th>
          <th width="12%">Comentarios</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" id="fee-1" class="form-control"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="fee-2" class="form-control autocomplete_txt"></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="fee-3" class="form-control changesNo"></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="fee-4" class="form-control changesNo"></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="fee-5" class="form-control totalLinePrice"></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="fee-6" class="form-control totalLinePrice"></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="fee-7" class="form-control totalLinePrice"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y el botón no hace nada

Comment: Lo vi así en el ejemplo, lo más raro es que si lo pongo en jsfiddle me funciona, pero no tengo puesto librerias mira http://jsfiddle.net/bwHnq/12/

Comment: Alberto, puse tu codigo en un snippet y si funciona... en tu jsfiddle has puesto jquery .. será que que no has importado la libreria?

Comment: al final del documento la tenog importada,   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> y la acabo de mover encima y tampoco funciona :S

Comment: y la consola te aparece algo?

Comment: Nose, acabo de coger el código entero con plantilla incluida lo e puesto en jsfiddle y tambien funciona

Comment: El problema parece que era el orden en el que se ejecutaba el script y funciona perfectamente aquí. Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como "no se puede reproducir"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que yo haría sería usar el antiguo método.
El botón tiene un atributo "onclick". Utilízalo para llamar a una función JS que contenga todo lo de dentro.
Viene a ser lo mismo, pero es por eliminar problemas, ya que al Ejecutar tu código en la web si que funciona.

```
<button onclick="newRow();" class="btn btn-success addmore" type="button" id="insert-more"> Add New Row</button>
```

Siendo newRow():

```
function newRow() {
  $("#mytable").each(function() {
    var tds = '<tr>';
    jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function() {
      tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
    });
    tds += '</tr>';
    if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
      $('tbody', this).append(tds);
    } else {
      $(this).append(tds);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado esto, y aun asi mi código anterior que funciona en jsfiddle tambíen me funciona ya, tenia el código encima dle html, lo puse debajo y ya funciona

Comment: Bueno, siempre está la opción de copiar, borrar, guardar y pegar. A veces los servidores se pueden quedar un poco pillados o también puede ser la caché.

Comment: Tener el JavaScript en la etiqueta directamente no es bueno, hace que el código sea más difícil de mantener  y rompe con la separación de lógica y presentación.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro lo sé, pero era por ver si era algo adicional, pero resultó ser un poltergeist.